# Authorize Attribute always returning false ASP.net MVC Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-identity, identity

When I decorate a method with an Authorize roles attribute it returns false everytime. I'm trying to limit access to an admin page for users in the "Admin" role only.

1. I have verified that the user im currently logged in as is in fact in the  "Admin" role.
2. I have tried to use a custom authorization attribute. Same result. I can add the code if needed.
3. I have found that the authorization attribute works for Users but not for Roles.
4. I believe this problem is somehow tied into the fact that the following does not work in my application:

   ```
   User.IsInRole("Admin").
   ```

   However, this statement does work:

   ```
   userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin")
   ```

Here is my code:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
    {

        //[AuthLog(Roles = "Admin")] //Custom authorization attribute
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult Users()
        {

            return View();
        }


    }
```

Maybe this can help with debugging:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core: V.2.1.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework: V.2.1.0

[image: Users]
[image: Users assigned to roles]
[image: User Id's assigned to roles]

I am open to suggestions on anything else I can post from my project in order to debug easier. I have scoured the stack for 2 weeks now.

**Update 1:** How user is logged in

```
// POST: /account/login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(AccountLoginModel viewModel)
    {
        // Ensure we have a valid viewModel to work with
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(viewModel);

        // Verify if a user exists with the provided identity information
        var user = await _manager.FindByEmailAsync(viewModel.Email);

        // If a user was found
        if (user != null)
        {
            // Then create an identity for it and sign it in
            await SignInAsync(user, viewModel.RememberMe);

            // If the user came from a specific page, redirect back to it
            return RedirectToLocal(viewModel.ReturnUrl);
        }

        // No existing user was found that matched the given criteria
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    private async Task SignInAsync(IdentityUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        // Clear any lingering authencation data
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        // Create a claims based identity for the current user
        var identity = await _manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Write the authentication cookie
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(identity.Name, isPersistent);
    }
```

Comment: Upon authenticating the user how are you constructing your Claimsprincipal?

Comment: @Jinish please see update 1

Comment: You could also create a FormsAuthenticationTicket manually. The constructor takes a parameter for userdata where you could add your roles upon authenticating. Post which add this to the httpresponse cookie collection. And then you could use your User.IsInRole

Answer (score 2):

The

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(identity.Name, isPersistent);
```

unfortunately doesn't store any roles with the identity. Thus, when the identity is recreated from the cookie, you have no roles. To verify try

```
this.User.IsInRole("Admin")
```

and you'll get `false`, even though the `userManager` tells you otherwise.

There are multiple workarounds.

You could for example switch to any other identity persistor, like the `SessionAuthenticationModule` which could store your username and roles in the cookie. You could follow [my tutorial](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/09/forms-authentication-revisited.html) on that.

Another approach would be to have an explicit role manager and use its feature that automatically causes your roles to be stored in another cookie, separate from the forms authentication cookie. This involves configuring the role provider and writing your own role provider that would be an adapter over the user manager.

Finally, you could forget forms authentication and use Identity's native way of issuing cookies, which would involve calling `SignInAsync` on the authentication manager.

Comment: Thank you for your time by looking into my issue. I would like to use the Identity native way. Can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: @Igorski88: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt173757%28v%3dvs.108%29

Comment: I have looked into the documentation. It outlines the SignInAsync but I already have that. I'm not certain what I need to change.  Is there any other documentation I can read that can either give me some examples or further reading to do. I really appreciate your time and would like to buy you a beer once solved.

Comment: Aren't you confusing your own `SignInAsync` that uses `FormsAuthentication` internally with the OWIN's way of issuing cookies with the `SignInManager`?

Comment: You are probably right but how do I use Owin to issue cookies. Can you give me an example.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity I can't believe you missed that. Read carefully the section *4. Signin* and pay attention on how they use the `SignInManager.SignInAsync` there.

Comment: I read the article and followed the tutorial but the SignInAsync isn't working because of the SignInManager. I started a new stack question but no one seems to understand because I'm getting no responses. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55929501/2557155. Would you mind taking a look? Every article I read on Google references core applications and my application is non core.