# SignInManager.SignInAsync does not work ASP.net MVC Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to store User Roles in cookies upon login using Identity "SignInManager.SignInAsync". I'm using the example from here(Section 4): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity. 
The error im getting is: `*Error CS0305 Using the generic type 'SignInManager<TUser, TKey>' requires 2 type arguments*`

I tried declaring the Signinmanager with: `private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string> _signInManager;`

Here is the code:

```
    // POST: /account/login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(AccountLoginModel viewModel)
    {

        // Ensure we have a valid viewModel to work with
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(viewModel);

        // Verify if a user exists with the provided identity information
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = viewModel.Email, Email = viewModel.Email };


        // If a user was found
        if (user != null)
        {

            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

            // If the user came from a specific page, redirect back to it
            return RedirectToLocal(viewModel.ReturnUrl);
        }

        // No existing user was found that matched the given criteria
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin

Comment: You seem to be using the type as variable here. The compilation error is somewhat misleading but assuming you correctly defined the SingInManager you must call it like _singInManager.SignInAsync etc

Comment: @gerwin I have not defined the SignInManager and I can't seem to find a good example of how to do that.